# GObject how to pass argument to signal

Tags: c, signals, parameter-passing, glib, gobject

Ok, so I have a custom GObject to handle Input events, to notify connected handlers I cerated a signal in the class_init_function:

```
static void sample_input_manager_class_init (SampleInputManagerClass *klass)
{
  sample_input_manager_signals[KEY_EVENT] = g_signal_new(
    "key-event",
    G_TYPE_FROM_CLASS(klass),
    G_SIGNAL_RUN_LAST,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    G_TYPE_NONE,
    1,
    G_TYPE_INT /* Keycode */
  );
}
```

Might usefull (at the top of the source file):

```
enum SAMPLE_INPUT_MANAGER_SIGNALS
{
  KEY_EVENT = 0,

  N_SIGNALS
};

static guint ssample_input_manager_signals[N_SIGNALS] = { 0 };
```

Now, I want to trigger the signal with the following call:

```
int key = 42;
g_signal_emit(manager, sample_input_manager_signals[KEY_EVENT], 0, key);
```

(Where manager is a valid instance, and key is an integer to represet characters) However, in my registered callback (`g_signal_connect`) I get totally random values like `-2073417152` (for any input integer, constant during runtime)

Am I missing anything to get this to work?

---

Edit #1:

Signal handler connection:

```
SampleInputHandler *input = sample_input_handler_new();
g_signal_connect(input, "key-event", G_CALLBACK(test_cb), NULL);
```

Callback:

```
void testcb(int key, gpointer data)
{
  printf("(%d)",key);
}
```

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## SOLUTION

Ok, so after a too-long time, i figured that the default callback signature in GLib is simmilar to this:

```
<ReturnType> callback (YourType *object[, <your arguments> ], gpointer data);
```

So in my issue I simply forgot the first parameter, so that instead of reading my integer, I actually read the memory pointer address of my object.

Comment: Correct. That is the template declaration of _all_ GObject signal handlers. The initial `object` and final `user_data` pointers are **always** present.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall exactly, thats what I forgot ;)